# Uncaught Typo error Cannot read property each of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a checkbox from the page which contains id that starts with the specific text `sku_cat`. I use this below function. But it is not working. I am getting an error 'Uncaught Typo error Cannot read property each of null.

HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sku[]" id="sku_cat123_blue" value="sku123">
<input type="checkbox" name="sku[]" id="sku_cat123_red" value="sku124">
<input type="checkbox" name="sku[]" id="sku_cat110_blue" value="sku125">
<input type="checkbox" name="sku[]" id="sku_cat115_blue" value="sku126">
```

Jquery script:

```
var category=$("input[type='checkbox'][id^='sku_cat']:checked").each();
```

Comment: Show us the html for the checkbox

Comment: check if `category` isn't `null` before run each loop

Comment: or check if that checkbox is checked?

Comment: @NexusDuck: HTML code has been added

Comment: works for me. are you sure this line is giving you error?

Comment: @Sojtin: Value is null. But there are ids in my HTML code. Then why does it comes as null value. Can you please confirm.

Comment: @Krishnakumar_Muraleedharan: Yes. I get this error. Even i am confused.

Comment: @GreenComputers, to get that error, this `$("input[type='checkbox'][id^='sku_cat']:checked")` should return null. But jQuery will return an empty object here, if condition does not satisfy. Thats why I wanted you to recheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var category = $("[id^=sku_cat]").each(function(index){
     console.log(index);
  });
```

Comment: I get 'null' in console.

Comment: check now...you will loop this the number of checkboxes you have . for me its working